# How to run process inside loop after previous process is finished? Java

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Long story short, i want to upload multiple images to my server using Retrofit 2. i want to loop the process of sending single image based on the size of List image but asynchronously, so second upload only run if the first upload is succeeded. Some people tell me i should send an Array of File to my server instead and parse the array there, but i want to know if there is an error while uploading in client side or not. that way if there is an error (network problem) on first loop, second loop will stop running.

I really don't have clear idea as for how to do the task above, but here is a start.

```
public class UploadAllImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void ,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        doSingleUpload(image);
        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(upload == succeeded){
          new UploadAllImage().execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is you might not know, but this is precisely how Google Drive and several other storage providers operate.  If a failure happens, you can flag your user that there was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably solve it like this:

```
public class UploadImages extends AsyncTask<Image, Integer, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Image... images) {
        List<Image> remainingImages = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(images));

        while (!remainingImages.isEmpty()) {
            boolean success = doSingleUpload(remainingImages.remove(0));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        // Handle the result of all uploads
    }
}
```